# Error in minecraft mod: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: rock

Tags: java, minecraft

I compile and work with mod for MC 1.7.10 in Idea without problem.
After put my mod into project: "Dark Matter" in AltLauncher it say that error `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: rock`

In block class i write this constructor

```
    public MyModBlock() {
        super(Material.rock);
        setBlockName(blockName);
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(this, blockName);
        GameRegistry.registerTileEntity(MyModTile.class, mymod.MODID + "-MyModTile");
    }
```

I think the class `Material.rock` has different version in my dev place and in "Dark Matter" and want try read variant of class field and select some in enum.

And question: can i enum class fileld

```
package net.minecraft.block.material;

public class Material {
    public static final Material air;
    public static final Material grass;
    public static final Material ground;
    public static final Material wood;
    public static final Material rock;
    public static final Material iron;
    public static final Material anvil;
    public static final Material water;
    public static final Material lava;
    public static final Material leaves;
...
```

something like that:

```
foreach (Material m in Material){
   if (m.name == 'rock' or m.name == 'stone' ) { myBlock = new MyModBlock(m) }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile a Minecraft mod, you can either make a version with deobfuscated MCP names by doing `./gradlew jar`, or a version with obfuscated SRG names by doing `./gradlew build`. The former only works inside of development environments, and the latter only works outside of development environments. The error you got is consistent with trying to run a deobfuscated build outside of a development environment.